# Is it possible to have a custom about page in electron (macOS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

Every Mac app has an about page.
Like this [image]
It looks fine but I want to be able to customize it like some other apps do. here is an example of this for docker.[image]

As far as I can see its possible but is it also possible with electron?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/about-window